# Unable to write XML 1.1 documents in Java

Tags: java, xml

How do you write an XML version 1.1 document in Java?  Java only seems to support version 1.0.

I tried using the `OutputKeys.VERSION` output property, as shown below, but that had no effect:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory fact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = fact.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.newDocument();

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.1");

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
transformer.transform(source, result);

System.out.println(writer.toString());
//still produces a 1.0 XML document
```

I tested the above code in the following JVMs:

- Linux: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-1~deb7u1)
- Linux: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)

I'd rather not have to include any external libraries, if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? I'm using Java 8 and for me your code works ... EDIT: it works with 7 as well.

Comment: Java 7.  Maybe it depends on the JVM implementation?  I'm using OpenJDK.  Here is the output of my `java -version`:
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: @Glorfindel Don't know if it matters, but setting `OutputKeys.STANDALONE` to "yes" has no effect either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using jdk1.8.0_40-b26 under Linux, if I run your code I obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

But if I add xalan-2.7.2 in my maven dependencies, I obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The explanation is that the xml librairies bundled with the jdk are quite old and the best solution is to use external librairies.

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/xml/jaxp/ReleaseNotes_150.html#versions), we see that the versions included in the reference implementation should be

> Xerces version 2.6.2 + (Xerces version 2.6.2 with controlled bug fixes)
>
> XSLTC version 2.6.0 + (XSLTC version 2.6.0 , with controlled bug fixes, based on the Xalan 2.6.0 release)

Just to confirm, I add xalan-2.6.0 in my maven dependencies, and I obtain again

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

So if you want to use XML 1.1, you have to use recent external xml libraries  like Xerces 2.11 and Xalan 2.7.2.